# How can I have different colors for hover states every time I scroll over it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not a coder but I want to add multiple colors to hover states. So for example, someone will hover over a link, and let's say the color will start off at #0c7740. When they hover over the same link it'll change to #ff4b00 and so forth. Now I want this applied to every link on my website, so it'll be universal.

The array of colors I want on the hover state are: #0c7740, #ff4b00, #2351fc, #5741d1, #c7c41c. (Would it be easy to switch these colors out when I want to change them?)

My website is on cargo collective and they use the below CSS code. I briefly looked up how to add javascript to the code and it says I would need to add a script tag to the HTML but I'm not entirely sure.

```
[data-predefined-style="true"] bodycopy a {
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
text-decoration: none;
}

[data-predefined-style="true"] bodycopy a:hover {
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}
```

Comment: This would need to be done using javascript. Do you have any javascript experience?

Comment: I saw that when I was looking up how to do it, but I have no experience with javascript. Bit of a newb here.

Comment: Be careful with which colors you use to make sure that they all have appropriate color contrast. Also, it'd be much simpler to apply an animation that slowly animates through the various color options, and it wouldn't require javascript.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you'll need to add some Javascript. This needs to go to between the script tags.

EDITED: now no need to add any stylesheet rules, javascript does it for you :-)

```
<script>
  colorArray = ['#0c7740', '#ff4b00', '#2351fc', '#5741d1', '#c7c41c'];
  colorIndex = 0;

  function setColorAndIncrement() {
    document.querySelector('body').setAttribute('style', '--hoverColor:' + colorArray[colorIndex]);
    colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colorArray.length;
  }

  window.onload = (event) => {
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    style.sheet.insertRule("a:hover { color:var(--hoverColor);}");

    setColorAndIncrement();
    const anchorElements = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    anchorElements.forEach((anchorElement) => {
      anchorElement.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
        setColorAndIncrement();
      });
    });
  };
</script>
```

Demo here

```js
colorArray = ['#0c7740', '#ff4b00', '#2351fc', '#5741d1', '#c7c41c'];
  colorIndex = 0;

  function setColorAndIncrement() {
    document.querySelector('body').setAttribute('style', '--hoverColor:' + colorArray[colorIndex]);
    colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colorArray.length;
  }

  window.onload = (event) => {
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    style.sheet.insertRule("a:hover { color:var(--hoverColor);}");

    setColorAndIncrement();
    const anchorElements = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    anchorElements.forEach((anchorElement) => {
      anchorElement.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
        setColorAndIncrement();
      });
    });
  };
```

```html
<a href='one'>Link 1</a><br>
<a href='one'>Link 2</a><br>
<a href='one'>Link 3</a>
```

Comment: Ahh thank you for providing this! When I add it to the HTML section of my site it isn't working. Do I need to define anything via CSS? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I got it, just added var(--hoverColor) to the CSS, I missed that. Thank you so much!! :o)

Comment: yes!! this is so exciting

Comment: That's great to hear. Welcome to the world of coding. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: this is simpler than the one above

the only way to do such a thing is to use javascript!
Don't be scared though, it's easier than you think.
first you need to translate your current code in js.
With an "addEventListener" you can create the "hover":

```
element.addEventListener("mouseover", elementHover);
```

Element is a variable initialized as follows:

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll("bodycopy a");
```

ElementHover is a function, like "container" of all the code that need to be executed when you hover the element and initializes as follows:

```
function elementHover(){
   // this is a comment
   // first you need to create a "box" containing all the color option (it's called an array)
   var colorArray = ["#2B45AE","#2B4A3E","#4C1A13"]; // as many as you want
   // now create color variable that changes randomly every time
   var randomColorNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length); // colorArray.length is the number of color in colorArray 
   // now you just need to get the color!
   var randomColor = colorArray[randomColorNumber];
   // and just assign it
   element.style.color = randomColor;
}
```

Now if you hover the a it change but if you remove the mouse from it the color dont change, you have to tell javascript what to do when you remove the mouse from there

```
element.addEventListener("mouseout", elementDefault);

function elementDefault(){
    element.style.color = "#cc7a76"; // thise value is the default color
}
```

Now you have just to connect javascript to html, put the javascript file in the same folder as the .html file, than put this in the bottom of the html body

```
<script src="javascriptFileName.js"></script>
```

Html at the end should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <bodycopy>
        <a>Your text</a>
    </bodycopy>
    <script src="javascriptFileName.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript at the end should look like this:

```
// define element
var element = document.querySelectorAll("bodycopy a");

// event listeners
element.addEventListener("mouseover", elementHover);
element.addEventListener("mouseout", elementDefault);

// functions
function elementHover(){
    // this is a comment
    // first you need to create a "box" containing all the color option (it's called an array)
    var colorArray = ["#2B45AE","#2B4A3E","#4C1A13"]; // as many as you want
    // now create color variable that changes randomly every time
    var randomColorNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length); // colorArray.length is the number of color in colorArray 
    // now you just need to get the color!
    var randomColor = colorArray[randomColorNumber];
    // and just assign it
    element.style.color = randomColor;
}


function elementDefault(){
    element.style.color = "#cc7a76"; // thise value is the default color
}
```

This works on my pc and shoud be should be enough for you but I'm here for problems or clarifications

Comment: Your JS won't work because querySelectorAll returns an NodeList of elements. You'll have to iterate through it to get to each element. See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Would be more appropriate to call an array a "list" instead of a "box"